# How to store and fetch the response of in-app purchase in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in-app purchase in my project. The implementation worked well but I have a problem to store a response.

I unlocked the button and when I go through in-app purchase the button will be unlocked the response becomes true.

But when I go back the class from which I came this class, and jump back to this class again,  I got the button locked again because I am not able to store response.

I am doning this:

```
.h file
bool isPurchased;






 -(void) successfulPurchase:(EBPurchase*)ebp restored:(bool)isRestore identifier:(NSString*)productId receipt:(NSData*)transactionReceipt
{
NSLog(@"ViewController successfulPurchase");

// Purchase or Restore request was successful, so...
// 1 - Unlock the purchased content for your new customer!
// 2 - Notify the user that the transaction was successful.

if (!isPurchased)
{
   // If paid status has not yet changed, then do so now. Checking
   // isPurchased boolean ensures user is only shown Thank You message
   // once even if multiple transaction receipts are successfully
   // processed (such as past subscription renewals).

   isPurchased = YES;


   if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isPurchased"]     isEqualToString:@"true"]){

isPurchased = YES;
// do something

}
else{
isPurchased = NO;
//isFailed = NO;
 // do something  
}


   //-------------------------------------

   // 1 - Unlock the purchased content and update the app's stored settings.

   //-------------------------------------

   // 2 - Notify the user that the transaction was successful.

   NSString *alertMessage;

   if (isRestore) {
       // This was a Restore request.
       alertMessage = @"Your purchase was restored and the Game Levels Pack is now  unlocked for your enjoyment!";

   } else {
       // This was a Purchase request.
       alertMessage = @"Your purchase was successful and the Game Levels Pack is now   unlocked for your enjoyment!";


       //  if (my_unlock_button == TRUE) {
       buyButton.hidden=YES;                   // These are the buttons  I unlocked
       buybutton1.hidden=YES;                 // These are the buttons   I unlocked

       //}

   }

   UIAlertView *updatedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank You!"  message:alertMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [updatedAlert show];
   [updatedAlert release];
}
}
```

how to store and fetch the response so that I can check the response?

Any Idea or suggestions from experts would be highly welcome.

Comment: see [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

Comment: Please check this

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial


Happy Coding!!!...

Comment: and [this (MKStoreKit)](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit) - why implement everything yourself?

Comment: @AreebaKhan: why are you posting a link to same question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement it like.

When the purchase is successful set a `bool` in `NSUserDefaults` like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES ForKey:@"isPurchased"];
```

In the `viewDidLoad` of the class, write like:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isPurchased"])
{
   //Enable/show the button
}
else
{
   //disable/hide button
}
```

This is a nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial), please refer it also

Comment: Hey midhun MP.. Thanks for ur answer.It helped me alot. I've an issue .I can purchase one item by clicking on that particular cell. But my app also have a BuyEverything button to purchase all the items. What would be the code for this. I did this code for purchasing single item `[[KhulamIAPHelper sharedInstance:productIdentifiers] buyProduct:(SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row]];` and this code for purchasing all items  `[[KhulamIAPHelper sharedInstance:productIdentifiers] buyProduct:(SKProduct *) [_products firstObject]];`. It only purchases first product. How can i purhcase all products.

Comment: @Sushil: For purchasing all item, you can use a loop like : `for (int index = 0; index < [_products count]; index++)
{
[[KhulamIAPHelper sharedInstance:productIdentifiers] buyProduct:(SKProduct *) _products[index]];
}`

Comment: One more thing. I've added an image on BuyEverything button. I want that when all the products get purchased, BuyEverything's image must get hidden. I tried to hide it within the loop but can't hide.How would I get to know that all products have been purchased in both the cases 1). purchasing one by one 2). purchasing by clicking on BuyEverything Button... This is my last query. Please help resolving this.

Comment: @Sushil: You can keep a counter for individual purchase, when it reaches the product count, you can say that all the items were purchased. When the purchase all button is clicked you can also set the counter variable to product count.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed [storekit](https://github.com/idzDeveloper/IDZStoreKit) for non consumable product. You can try it. ;)

Happy coding!